# What kind of resources does the render distance in Minecraft mainly use?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, hardware

I'd like to set the Render Distance to 64 chunks (using Optifine) on Minecraft: Java Edtion without getting any lags or low FPS.

I have an Intel Core i7-10700K and 16Gb of RAM, and I allocate 14Gb of RAM to Minecraft. I use the integrated GPU for now (Intel UHD630, I will get a discrete GPU later).

So my question is, what kind of resources does the Render Distance in Minecraft mainly use? Is it the RAM (it is stated within the Optifine mod that I must allocate at least 4Gb of RAM to Minecraft in order to set a render distance higher than 48 chunks), the CPU, or the GPU ?

I can't figure out which of them is the most heavily used when setting high render distances.

Comment: I can't answer because I only play Bedrock edition on Xbox, but, maybe you can see it for yourself. Open Windows' task manager, switch to advanced > performance tab, minimize it, and play some Minecraft. You'll be able to see the % of CPU, RAM, etc used. Considering it's render distance I'd say GPU, but Minecraft is weird so who knows :)

Comment: @AJPerez i would think cpu would probally be important too, as calculating all that stuff isnt easy, and you would also need alot of ram to handle all that data for the hundreds of chunks

Comment: @AJPerez I did look at the Windows' Task Manager while playing and using high render distances, and the cpu did not go above 5% use, the RAM went over 10Gb although I defined the maximum to 14Gb, and the GPU usage was all the way up to 100%. However considering my GPU is an integrated GPU, I get 100% usage of it most of the time so it doesn't help me knows if it is related to the high render distance or not. So I'll stick with your answer while I'm using the iGPU. Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 1):

Minecraft mostly uses a single core of the CPU for chunk rendering.  More then twice the ram as the game is going to use is too much, but 12GB seems appropriate for this distance. More then that tends to make the game run slower regardless due to garbage collection.  The GPU can help, but given that minecraft is CPU-heavy to begin with, the CPU is by far the bottleneck for most desktop PCs.

Also, just so you know in 1.13+ even OptiFine cannot push the render distance above 32 chunks.

Answer (score -1):

I use Yungs Better Caves and edit the config to significantly reduce the large amount of caves you have to load in and the Entity Culling mod as well to increase fps.

Comment: So basically that mod makes it that the mines that are in the chunk, but under the ground and not visible are not loaded, thus boosting FPS? If you could add some explanation on how that config helps, if you know how it does, it would help your answer a lot.

Comment: Also, this is not exactly an answer to the question per say, but does get to fixing the issue the poster is having.

Comment: I literally reduce the amount of caves and make them rare which both increases FPS which you can trade for higher render distance and makes caves more special to find.